# Flow type issue with inline webpack loader

Tags: javascript, webpack, flowtype

I am using `sass-variable-loader` with webpack and because of limitation with extending webpack configuration, I just want to use it inline this way:

```
import variables from '!!sass-variable-loader!../../../src/styles/variables.scss'
```

This works as expected but when I try to run flow, it exits with this error:

```
import variables from '!!sass-variable-loader!../../../src/styles/variables.scss'
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ !!sass-variable-loader!../../../src/styles/variables.scss. Required module not found
```

Is there a way for Flow not to fail on this line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.flowconfig` file, you can add the following (I have the initial !s optional, since they are, depending on your purpose):

```
[options]
module.name_mapper='^\(!!\)?sass-variable-loader!.+\.scss$' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/Stub.js.flow'
```

And `Stub.js.flow` looks like:

```
declare module Stub {
  declare var exports: { [key: string]: string };
}
```

You don't need to call the file that, but you'll need one that looks like that.